# Mounting EFS by IP Address in Userdata in Cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, autoscaling, amazon-efs, automount

I currently have a Cloudformation Template that launches an autoscaling group, with an accompanying launchconfiguration with a userdata section. In this same template, I have a MountTarget. This mount target references an EFS volume in a separate stack. I want to put the mount command:

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 X.X.X.X:/ efs_data_mount_point
```

in my userdata, but I am not sure how to retrieve the IP Address of the mount target. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried exporting the IP address from the other stack and importing it in this stack? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html